# JAVA: How to store logged in user

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working in a school Java project with MySql using Eclipse. I already did the login screen and validated the credentials against the DB´s users table. Now I need to use the userid of the logged in user to show it in several JFrames. Is there a way to store that userid in a type of global variable that can be accessed from anywhere in the system? The project has a Menu Bar form that is open all the time, I could create a varible there and access it from any form but I do not think that is the correct way of solving this issue.

Comment: There are several questions: Are you using a client/server architecture or just a single application? If single application: Can only one user login to the application at the same time?

Comment: The login screen has a field where the user enters her login name, correct? Can't you save that in a member variable of some java class and write a `getUser()` method that returns that value? Then any code that needs the user's login can call the `getUser()` method.

Comment: You can store the userid in an HttpSession.

Comment: It is a desktop single application. More than one user can login but they would need the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide any information about the technology which you are using. So I can only give a generic answer based on the Java programming language.

You can place a static variable in any of your classes. This variable will exist only once in memory regardless how many instances of the class you create. It is even accessible without having an instance.

Example:

```
public class GlobalData 
{
    public static String userName=null;
}
```

You can simply access the member variable everywhere:

```
GlobalData.userName="IronMan";
```

Comment: Sorry about that, the question says I'm using Java and Eclipse and MySql for the database. Regarding the GlabalData class, when I should create it? in the login screen? does it not dissappear when I disposed that screen?

Comment: @Ronald Valdivia It's static so it'll create itself. You just need to assign the userName when login is successful (credentials pass tests)